# exclusive lock over orientdb storage

Tags: orientdb

I think about implementing an exclusive lock mechanism based on orientdb `select lock record`, but it doesn't seem to work, at least with v2.1.5. Basically, in console #1 I open a remote connection to GratefulDeadConcerts and send the following commands:

```
begin
select from v where @rid = #9:0 lock record
```

And from console #2, the same sequence which I expected to fail somehow, but this doesn't happen, instead data is returned.
I base my attempt on what the documentation says about lock clause in select:

> LOCK manage the locking strategy. By default is "default", that means
>   release the lock once the record is read, while "record" means to keep
>   the record locked in exclusive mode in current transaction till the
>   transaction has been finished by a commit or rollback operation.